# Born–Landé equation for isolated ions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, ionization-energy

Wikipedia says what the lattice energy of a crystalline ionic compound can be calculated, based on some approximations, by Born–Landé equation:

$E = \frac{N_{A}Mz^{+}z^{-}e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon r_{0}}$

where:

```
NA = Avogadro constant;
M = Madelung constant, relating to the geometry of the crystal;
z+ = numeric charge number of cation
z− = numeric charge number of anion
e = elementary charge, 1.6022×10−19 C
ε0 = permittivity of free space

    4πε0 = 1.112×10−10 C2/(J·m)

r0 = distance to closest ion
n = Born exponent, typically a number between 5 and 12, determined experimentally by measuring the compressibility of the solid, or derived theoretically.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Land%C3%A9_equation

If I want to calculate the energy of only one ionic pair, can I just assume what:
M =1
$N$=1  (number of molecules)

I guess,  $n$ parameter, which comes from molecular repulsion, is still needed even if the molecule is "free" and not embedded into the crystal.

Comment: is it a single free-standing ionic pair, or a single ionic pair in a crystal?

Comment: I meant a single free-standing ion pair.

Comment: in that case just use the Coulomb formula, no need to use Born-Lande

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Born–Landé equation is for calculating approximate lattice energy. Lattice energy is meant to be the amount of energy you need to break the bonding of one mole of the lattice. In a lattice, of course, you have bonding forces between ionic compounds but also interactions between all other lattice components. So you cannot take equations, which were derived for lattices, to calculate free molecule forces or energies. I can recommend taking a look at Born-Oppenheimer approximation to get a better understanding of interaction terms (and why you can neglect some of these) in a solid state material or even molecules. [Wikipedia Born–Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation)

A more understandable introduction to bonding energies and forces is given at [TU Graz - Chemical Bonds](http://lamp.tu-graz.ac.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/crystalbinding/bonds/bonds.php). Since the strongest interaction for an ionic bond is the electrostatic force, you cannot easily calculate an amount of energy to break the bond because there is no distance limit for this force (Coulomb's law). What you can calculate is an amount of energy you need to push the ionic compounds a fixed distance away from each other, but - if you have nothing else (atoms/ fermions -> interaction -> forces) in your system - the ionic compunds will always get back to the energy ground state which would be there normal ion-bounded state.